# unsupported operend type(s) for -:' str' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

```
import datetime

birthday=[int(i) for i in str(20000707)]

today=datetime.datetime.now()

today=today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

a=birthday[0:4]

a=''.join(str(i) for i in a)

a=int(a)

b=birthday[4:6]

b=''.join(str(i) for i in b)

b=int(b)

c=birthday[6:8]

c=''.join(str(i) for i in c)

c=int(c)

dob=datetime.date(a,b,c)

aged=(today-dob).days

agey=aged/365

print agey
```

It throws the following error:

> aged=(today-dob).days
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.date'

Comment: The problem is that in the line `aged=(today-dob).days` you do a subtraction. In that subtraction you try to subtract `dob` (this is type datetime.date) from `today` (this is type string)

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles and runs and displays the correct amount of years:

Note I made the following changes:

1. Remove the line that converts `today` to string format
2. Change `dob` from a `datetime.date` type to `datetime.datetime` type
3. Remove unnecessary lines of code

Here's the code:

```
import datetime
birthday=[int(i) for i in str(20000707)]
today=datetime.datetime.now()
a=int(''.join(str(i) for i in birthday[0:4]))
b=int(''.join(str(i) for i in birthday[4:6]))
c=int(''.join(str(i) for i in birthday[6:8]))
dob = datetime.datetime(a,b,c)
aged = (today-dob).days
agey = aged / 365
print(agey)

>> 17.46849315068493
```

Comment: `[int(i) for i in str(20000707)]` and all the following parsing are totally unnecessary. You can just use simple modular arithmetic.